# WF-3620 shows wrong computer name for Mac when selecting scan destination

Tags: macos, home-networking, epson-workforce

This is kind of a random question. I migrated from a Mac that had been named `old-name` to a new Mac that is named `new-name` and have updated macOS several times. I also have an Epson WF-3620. In order to scan to this computer, I have to select `old-name.hom` from the network computer list on my printer. Any ideas as to how I can update this?

For reference, here's the output of `scutil` on the Mac.

```
new-name:~ username$ scutil --get HostName
HostName: not set
new-name:~ username$ scutil --get LocalHostName
new-name
new-name:~ username$ scutil --get ComputerName
new-name
```

Comment: Wild guess... System Prefs > Network > [current connection] > Advanced > WINS... what's the NetBios name? Alternatively System Prefs > Sharing > Computer Name...

Comment: The NetBios names from ethernet and wi-fi are both correct, as is the "Sharing" computer name. Thanks for the wild guesses! :)